# What legal character does the Istanbul document have?

Tags: international, war

The Budapest memorandum and the Istanbul document are two important documents thought to guarantee security & stability in the regions of the former Soviet Union. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Ukrainian_War#Background)

The Instanbul documents states:

> "We reaffirm the inherent right
> of each and every participating State to be free to choose or change its security arrangements,
> including treaties of alliance, as they evolve. "

I have heard that the Instanbul document is a declaration of intent, not a treaty. What is the legal character of this document? Is it legally binding? If yes has Russia retreated from that agreement?

[Istanbul document](https://www.osce.org/mc/39569)

Comment: A little more context would be helpful.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 3):

This is what is usually called a *declaration* (that the Instanbul Document is sometimes called a declaration of *intent* has no legal significance). Declarations are not binding in the way that treaties are. They don't independently create obligations to the world. But they can play a role in establishing or reflecting customary international law; can provide evidence of *opinio juris*; and domestic legal systems can look to them in applying a presumption of conformity.

The Universal Declaration of Human Rights and the U.N. Declaration on the Rights of Indigenous Peoples are two other declarations. They both happen to reflect a lot of customary international law: much of the content is binding even though it also appears in these declarations.

Comment: Is there a difference between a declaration and a declaration of intent?